# how to fill an author field with current username

Tags: python, django

I have looked at a lot of different places but none of their solutions work.  This is most likely to do them being for older versions of django or my own stupidity.  So I am making a blog type of app that for some reason is called reviews instead of blog... anyway I need to automatically fill up an author field with the username of the logged in user. Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#vars

# Create your models here.
class reviews(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

and forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import reviews
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
class CreatePost_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = reviews
        exclude = ['author']
        fields = ['title', 'body',]
```

and views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from .forms import CreatePost_form
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
def reviewlist(request):
    return render
def index(request, ):
    return render(request, template_name="index.html")
def CreatePost(request):
    form = CreatePost_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/reviews/succesfulpost')
    return render(request, "reviews/CreatePostTemplate.html", {'form':form})
def succesfulpost(request):
    return render(request, "reviews/succesfulpost.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def CreatePost(request):
    form = CreatePost_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/reviews/succesfulpost')
```

As simple as that. Rather than actually saving and committing the data, you simply save without committing then you're able to change the value of the excluded field.

Comment: uhh ...it didn't work it deosn't show in my reviews list view or on the admin review table

Comment: Then, you're doing something wrong. That should do for you, if you're actually logged in and request.user isn't null. Check if request.user is null or not, or try by querying the author table and storing a random author there.

Comment: yea i dont know i musta screwed somthing up

Comment: ok s I did a DB reset and now it says None for the author instead of  blank, but it does return the user name with the {{ request.user }} in the html template so i know someone is logged in.  The view just wont register that someone is

Comment: @livingcobble You **must be logged in**  before accessing the `CreatePost`

Comment: the {{ reqeust.user }} in the layout shows the loged in user name in the top of the page.  If I click logout that disappears, and then if I go to the login page and input a valid username and password it re-appears. Plus I imported login_required and used that it still lets me go to the create_post page